# Process all matches in a file in multiple steps and replace some of the matches

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to find all matches of a regex in a file and replace them. I would like to find matches in multiple steps. For example, I want to first find the pattern that come between two $IDENTIFIER_ , then inside that pattern replace all $ONE with $TWO.

This what I have so far:

```
$entireFile = "Some random text here var_a 4456 var_b var_c 1122 var_d var_e 559 var_f Some random text here ";
my $ONE_="1";
my $TWO_="2";
my $IDENTIFIER_ =  "\\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\b";
my $id1;
my $id2;
my $item;
while ($entireFile =~ m/($IDENTIFIER_)(.*?)($IDENTIFIER_)/g)
{
  $id1  = $1; 
  $item = $2;
  $id2  = $3;
  #Check to see if $item has $ONE and replace with $TWO
  if ($item =~ s/(.*?)$ONE_(.*?)/$1$TWO_$2/g )
  {
    print $id1.$item.$id2."\n" ;
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
var_c 2222 var_d
```

What I need help with is how to print the rest of the file (the text before the first match, the text between subsequent matches, and the text after the last match).

Comment: You should focus a bit more on describing what an identifier should look like, and show some examples of input and expected output. Also, naming a variable `$ONE_` (with underscore on the end) is asking to make typos.

Comment: I added the value of $IDENTIFIER_ to the code

Answer (score 2):

```
$entireFile = "Some random text here var_a 4456 var_b".
              " var_c 1122 var_d var_e 559 var_f Some random text here ";
my $ONE_="1";
my $TWO_="2";
my $re_id = qr/\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/;
while ($entireFile =~ s/($re_id.*?)$ONE_(.*?$re_id)/$1$TWO_$2/) { } 
print $entireFile;
```

If you really want to match in two phases:

```
$entireFile = "Some random text here var_a 4456 var_b".
              " var_c 1122 var_d var_e 559 var_f Some random text here ";
my ($ONE_, $TWO_) = ("1", "2");
my $re_id = qr/\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/;
my $printed=0;
while ($entireFile =~ /($re_id)(.*?)($re_id)/g) {
  my ($id1, $item, $id2) = ($1, $2, $3);
  my ($start, $end, $length) = ($-[0], $+[0], $+[0]-$-[0]);
  if ($printed < $start) {
    print substr($entireFile, $printed, $-[0]-$printed);
    $printed = $start;
  }
  if ($item =~ s/(.*?)$ONE_(.*?)/$1$TWO_$2/g ) { 
    print $id1.$item.$id2."\n" ;
    $printed = $end;
  } else {
    print substr($entireFile, $printed, $length)."\n";
    $printed = $end;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are matching and replacing in one single step. I was wondering if I could do this in multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a function that you execute within the substitution.

e.g.

```
$entireFile = "Some random text here var_a 4456 var_b var_c 1122 var_d var_e 559 var_f Some random text here ";
my $ONE_="1";
my $TWO_="2";
my $IDENTIFIER_ =  "\\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\b";

$entireFile =~ s/($IDENTIFIER_)(.*?)($IDENTIFIER_)/$1 . inner_func($2) . $3/egs;
print( $entireFile );

sub inner_func {
    my ( $text ) = @_;

    $text =~ s/$ONE_/$TWO_/g;
    return( $text );
}
```

The `/e` flag instructs the substitution operator (`s///`) to execute the replacement text as if it were code. This can be especially useful for recursive descent parsing...

If you use `/s` as a flag on your substitution you are also telling the search-and-replace to treat newlines like any other character - enabling you to perform this global replace across lines (if you've slurped the entire file into your variable in the first place).